# How does an open() system call return a file descriptor?

Tags: unix

I want to know what happens in the kernel when an open() system call is invoked? How does it return a file descriptor for a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel creates internally a structure containing additional informations about the file you did just open. This structure holds informations such as the `inode` number, the name of the file on the file system, its size, its associated superblock, etc ...

In fact, within the kernel, it is the [`VFS (Virtual File System)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system) that handles I/O operations on a file will it be local (on you hard disk) or remote (located on an FTP server for instance like `ftpfs` does).

Every file systems on GNU/Linux *implements* the same mechanisms of opening/reading/writing/closing files. This ensures every developers don't have to bother about what kind of file they are trying to access, no matter what kind of file you are interacting with, the same open(), read() ... APIs can be used. You can find additional informations on what the *VFS* is [here](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix01/full_papers/kroeger/kroeger_html/node8.html) and [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-linux-filesystem/) (great article by IBM).

Finally, each file descriptor that is returned by let's say `open` is relative to your program, so the first file you might be opening will be associated to the file descriptor `3` and so on ... It is possible to find out what file descriptors are binded to each process on many GNU/Linux distributions via `/proc/{pid_of_your_process}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to dive deep, you can browse the source for many unix variants.  For linux, check out http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9/fs/open.c -- search for `SYSCALL_DEFINE3(open,`  to get to the actual "open" syscall.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel:

- looks for the file (hard drive, usb, named pipes, standard streams, ...)
- if everything went well, saves itself a descriptor that you opened the file
- *returns you a descriptor*
- if you close() or the process exits, releases it's info about your open()